# ARM boot code in xen not booting when paging is enabled

Tags: paging, virtual-memory, arm64, xen, hypervisor

I am trying to understand the xen boot code for arm64. Simply took the head.S and compiled with aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (have hard coded the required macros inside the head.S). It is start for some level and stopping after enabling paging (no print at all)

console printing:

```
- UART enabled -
- UART enabled -
- CPU 00000000 booting -
- Current EL 00000008 -
- Xen starting at EL2 -
- Zero BSS -
- Setting up control registers -
- Turning on paging  -
```

anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: paging isn’t working.

Idea 2: you ran out of things to print.

So, to choose between 1 & 2, maybe have a peek at the source, and see if you should expect to see any more output.   If you should, then 1 is pretty much the answer.

Now, selecting [1]:
Idea 1a:  Your memory map is wrong, so the pages that it set up make no sense.

Idea 1b:  You don’t have the device control registers for the console properly defined in the memory map, so it is unable to write new messages out.

If you made it this far, you know more, but not nearly enough.

Comment: thx for the reply.Yes my problem is in paging only. I haven't modified anything in my paging related codes.For testing i disabled the mmu exactly after enable the mmu (and added print after this)to check whether the uart (console print come from scif uart) having problem or code address translation having problem. No prints after paging enable.So my boot code address translation itself having problem.But why, this code directly from opensrc,thats why i am worrying. Only difference is i am loading my image at 0x480000000 instead of 0x200000 (based on my bootloader requirement).

Comment: To understand paging better now i like to see the some simple samples in net. But i could not find any paging related examples for arm64 :( . Is any one having simple baremetal program for the same...

Comment: One of the bits that turning on paging must do is to create a unity (V=P) for at least the code space which is turning on the pager.   Failure to do so means that the processor no longer has a place to fetch instructions from; which likely results in a trap, which the mapping for the handler likely isn’t right, eventually leading to shutdown

Comment: Have you considered trying to run it under qemu?   Then you can single step with gdb.   Years ago, qemu didn’t support EL2, but you can mod the startup to setup EL1 instead, get the logic right, then sed it back to EL2...

Comment: thx for the support. Now it is working (there was a typo mistake in tcr_el1 config which let to this problem)